# Serving REACT component using express is not working (just html file is rendered)

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, mern

Hello I am learning MERN stack and I have problem with serving my react component this is server.js code

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'html')
app.engine('html', function (path, options, callback) {
  fs.readFile(path, 'utf-B', callback)
})

const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors({
  'origin': '*',
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  'preflightContinue': false,
  'optionsSuccessStatus': 204
}))

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/build'), 'index.html')
  res.end()
})

app.use('/*', (req, res) => res.status(404).send())

const isDev = true
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).json({
    error: 500,
    message: 'Internal Server Error!',
    stack: isDev
      ? err.stack
      : null
  })
})

const port = 8080
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('app running at localhost:' + port)
})
```

Folder structure

```
build
  bundle.js
  index.html
client
  App.js
  index.html
  index.js
server
  server.js
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

There is no issues viisble in console - HTML is rendering properly however React component  is not visible.

this is my index.html file:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
  <meta name='author' content='Bartosz Ciach'>
  <meta name='description'
    content='Check how your habits, weather conditions and daily activities affect your life & health.'>
  <meta name='keywords' content=''>
  <link rel='icon' type='image/svg+xml' href='assets/icons/favicon.ico'>
  <title>Doctor Crohn</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='app'></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

and my webpack.config.js file code below

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
  entry: './client/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './client',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'standard-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loaders: ['url-loader', 'img-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

I tried various things and unfortunately its still doesnt work as it should

Comment: Maybe this could answer your question:
[serving-static-html-into-a-react-component](https://medium.com/@justintulk/serving-static-html-into-a-react-component-using-node-express-8cb9fc9194df)

Comment: 1. Is there a reference to your bundle.js inside your index.html? 2. With the current structure and server code, you won't be able to serve static assets from the build directory (where your bundle is located), only from the client directory - that seems wrong by the way, it'd be better to have Webpack rebuild index.html using the one located in the client directory as a template, and serve everything from within the build directory. This can be done with the `html-webpack-plugin` npm module. It will also dynamically insert the call to your compiled bundle.js, thus also solving point 1.

Comment: I just added code snippets

Comment: Yeah, so from your index.html, the bundle.js file is expected to be located in the same directory as the index.html file, which is not the case according to your folder structure.

Comment: Basically, you have two choices here. 1. Change the output path in your webpack config to `/client` instead of `/build` which should normally work with your current server config, but is not great overall as it outputs production builds right into a source folder, or 2. change your server config to serve assets and index.html from the `/build` directory instead of `/client` and find a way to generate a copy of index.html into the `/build` folder during the build process (you can also copy it manually, at least the first time to see if it works).

Comment: @Jaxx I changed things like u said (edited my topic) but still it doesn't work

Comment: @Rachomir If html is coming properly then make sure the `bundle.js` is pointing to right `bundle.js` in `index.html`.You can do `View Page source` and then click on `bundle.js` in script tag.

Comment: it still doesn't work - any other ideas? I can run it using npm start however node server/server.js doesn't work - just html is rendered (and now its not rendered properly)

Comment: One more thing. Try changing the call to bundle.js inside index.html from `/bundle.js` to `./bundle.js` because I cannot tell for sure where the absolute root of your served content is. This will really place bundle relative to index (and expect it in the same directory).

Comment: Also, remember to use your browser dev tools to figure out what is going on. In the network tab, do you see bundle.js being requested but not found, for instance?

Comment: Now its like injecting empty html file to browser (without any code just <body><pre></pre></body>)


But html file copied to build folder looks exactly the same as in client folder

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you had added the HtmlWebpackPlugin... great. Can you show me the content of the index.html being output (meaning the one in the /build directory)? You should also remove any reference to bundle.js from the source index.html (the one in /client) as the plugin will take care of adding that reference for you.

Comment: Updated html file code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160295/discussion-between-jaxx-and-rachomir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to bring closure to this question.

The last hurdle to get the app to render properly was to modify a couple of lines in the `server.js` file to point correctly to the `/build` directory. Considering the folder structure, and the location of the `/build` directory relative to the `server.js` file location, the following lines were updated:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build'), 'index.html')
  res.end()
})
```

Comment: Jaxx is there any chance I can have one more question with problem I approached?

Comment: that would be great

Comment: @Rachomir you can still use the chat link from the comments below your original question. Leave me a message there & i'll be happy to help.